# Upload worksheet instance with gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a template worksheet in a spreadsheet that I need to duplicate to another spreadsheet. How can I achieve this with gspread?

```
        gs = gspread.oauth()
        template_sh = gs.open_by_key(TEMPLATE_SHEET_ID)
        template_ws = template_sh.worksheet('Template')

        target_sh = gs.open_by_key(TARGET_SHEET_ID)
```

Is there anything like

```
        target_sh.upload(template_ws)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to copy the specification sheet in `TEMPLATE_SHEET_ID` to the target Spreadsheet of `TARGET_SHEET_ID`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
TEMPLATE_SHEET_ID = "###" # Please set Spreadsheet ID.
TARGET_SHEET_ID = "###" # Please set Spreadsheet ID.

gs = gspread.oauth()
template_sh = gs.open_by_key(TEMPLATE_SHEET_ID)
template_ws = template_sh.worksheet('Template')

res = template_ws.copy_to(TARGET_SHEET_ID)
```

- When this script is run, "Template" sheet of `TEMPLATE_SHEET_ID` is copied to the Spreadsheet of `TARGET_SHEET_ID`.

#### Reference:

- [copy_to(spreadsheet_id)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.0/api.html?highlight=copy#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.copy_to)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, I just could not find the method in the API.

Comment: @DavideL Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.